# Снять выделения текста JS

Tags: html, javascript

Как можно снять выделение текста в `input type=text`. Ведь при имитации фокуса вида на этот объект, текст в нем автоматически выделяется. Как это убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Убрать выделение с текста](http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/13568-javascript-ubrat-vydelenie-s-teksta.html)

```
<textarea onMouseOver="this.select();" onMouseOut="this.value +=' '; this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);">какой-либо текст</textarea>
```